# 13 genes, any one of which may be "on" or "off"; how many combinations are possible?

Tags: combinatorics

If I have 13 genes that can either be in an "on" state or an "off" state, how many total possibilities exist for this set?

Comment: Hint : Try some small cases first, and see if you can find a pattern. Example, if you have one gene what are the possibilities?  If you have 2, what are they?  Continue and after a while you should see the pattern and get the answer.

Answer (score 3):

There can be 2 states per gene. In total, there will be $2^{13}$ possibilities.